# Чем объясняется постановка/непостановка запятой перед вторым союзом и?

Tags: пунктуация

"И столь длительным и столь успешным существованием это заведение
обязано личному рецепту одной домохозяйки".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это зависит от того, к чему относятся союзы.

Если это повторяющийся союз *И*, то запятая нужна:
**И столь длительным, и столь успешным** существованием это заведение обязано...

Если первое *И* относится ко всему предложению, то запятая не нужна:
**И** столь длительным и столь успешным **существованием это заведение обязано...**

Поэтому, чтобы принять решение о постановке/непостановке запятой, нужен более широкий контекст.

Comment: А лучше убрать одно "столь":И столь длительным и успешным существованием это заведение обязано...

Comment: @Людмила Если первое *и* относится ко всему предложению, то Вы абсолютно правы. Рассуждая от противного, если есть два "столь", значит первое *и*, скорее всего, не относится ко всему предложению: И столь длительным, и столь успешным существованием это заведение обязано (запятая нужна)

Answer (score 3):

Возможны три варианта:

**1) Союз И...И повторяющийся**

И столь длительным,  и столь успешным существованием это заведение обязано личному рецепту одной домохозяйки.

**2) Первый союз И – присоединительный**

И столь длительным и  успешным существованием это заведение обязано личному рецепту одной домохозяйки.

**3)  союз И – одиночный соединительный.**

Столь длительным  и столь успешным существованием это заведение обязано личному рецепту одной домохозяйки.

Comment: Только нужно обратить внимание читателя, что во втором варианте удалено второе "столь".